# How do I combine these newcolumn ifelse statements into one for loop?

Tags: r, dplyr

This is probably a face-palm question but I haven't been able to combine the code below into one for-loop. When I try to combine it all of the values return as null rather than 1's and 0's when I do it this way.

```
dfs4 <- dfs4 %>%
  add_column(Journal_Article = if_else(grepl("Journal Article", dfs4$pubtypes), 1, 0), )

dfs4 <- dfs4 %>%
  add_column(Meta_Analysis = if_else(grepl("Meta-Analysis", dfs4$pubtypes), 1, 0), )

dfs4 <- dfs4 %>%
  add_column(Systematic_Review = if_else(grepl("Systematic Review", dfs4$pubtypes), 1, 0), )

dfs4 <- dfs4 %>%
  add_column(Case_Reports = if_else(grepl("Case Reports", dfs4$pubtypes), 1, 0), )

dfs4 <- dfs4 %>%
  add_column(Observational_Study = if_else(grepl("Observational Study", dfs4$pubtypes), 1, 0), )

dfs4 <- dfs4 %>%
  add_column(Randomized_Controlled_Trial = if_else(grepl("Randomized Controlled Trial", dfs4$pubtypes), 1, 0), )

dfs4 <- dfs4 %>%
  add_column(Comparative_Study = if_else(grepl("Comparative Study", dfs4$pubtypes), 1, 0), )

dfs4 <- dfs4 %>%
  add_column(Review = if_else(grepl("Review", dfs4$pubtypes), 1, 0), )

dfs4 <- dfs4 %>%
  add_column(Clinical_Trial = if_else(grepl("Clinical Trial", dfs4$pubtypes), 1, 0), )

dfs4 <- dfs4 %>%
  add_column(Historical_Article = if_else(grepl("Historical Article", dfs4$pubtypes), 1, 0), )

dfs4 <- dfs4 %>%
  add_column(Biography = if_else(grepl("Biography", dfs4$pubtypes), 1, 0), )

dfs4 <- dfs4 %>%
  add_column(Multicenter_Study = if_else(grepl("Multicenter Study", dfs4$pubtypes), 1, 0), )

dfs4 <- dfs4 %>%
  add_column(Evaluation_Study = if_else(grepl("Evaluation Study", dfs4$pubtypes), 1, 0), )

dfs4 <- dfs4 %>%
  add_column(Portrait = if_else(grepl("Portrait", dfs4$pubtypes), 1, 0), )
```

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

A base R option using `lapply` -

```
values <- c("Journal Article", "Meta-Analysis", "Systematic Review", "Case Reports")

name <- make.names(values)

dfs4[name] <- lapply(values, function(x) as.integer(grepl(x, dfs4$pubtypes)))
```